# Does/Will Google support NDK C++ crashes in Firebase Crash Reporting?

Tags: android, android-ndk, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have tried to find out from the documentation whether Google is supporting NDK C++ crashes in the newly released [Firebase Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/). So far I have seen only Java crashes support. 
Does any one know if Google is planning to add support in the near future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the initial beta version, Firebase [Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android) only supports collecting Java crashes (on Android).

Can't make any comments on future support, but its certainly an important area to consider for us.

Comment: is there a feature request issue somewhere that we can vote/star to show interest in this? Crashlytics and Google's own Breakpad are able to record NDK crashes. Without having that functionality, Firebase crash reporting can't (at least for us) act as a replacement for either of those other services.

Comment: No place to star, but feel free to upvote this question!

Comment: Any update on this feature request? This would really be beneficial for our c++ game engine core!

Comment: Is there any access to the stored Crash Reporting data from the REST API?

Answer (score 3):

After google's acquisition of fabric and their claim that crashlytics will become the [main crash reporting tool](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/FabricJoinsGoogle17.html) for firebase; I would say that crashlytics is the way to go. Crashlytics also has good [ndk support](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html)