# Firebase Crash Reporting - Does it support NDK now?

Tags: android, c++, firebase, android-ndk, firebase-crash-reporting

Does Firebase Crash reporting support NDK / C++ in the latest version?

Has anybody tested it and how are the results?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup. Since that doesn't include Crash Reporting, I assume it's not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Crash Reporting currently does not support NDK/native code.  The team recommends use of Crashlyics (acquired by Google) for NDK crash reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Crash Reporting automatically generates reports for fatal errors (or uncaught exceptions). However, you can also generate reports in instances where you catch an exception but still want to report the occurrence. To report such an error, you can follow the steps listed on [official Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android) :

> **Some time You got an email from google Firebase to your registered email address to solve out bug**

only supports **collecting Java crashes** (on Android).

For more information look this [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331845/does-will-google-support-ndk-c-crashes-in-firebase-crash-reporting)

Comment: I've seen this SOF post, but it was one year ago. Maybe things changed since then?